# Como puedo hacer un arreglo asi

Tags: java, eclipse

1. Pedir nombre desde teclado
2. Descomponer las letras del nombre en un arreglo.
3. Calcular el peso de cada letra dependiendo de la posición en el abecedario.
4. Sumar todos los pesos de cada letra del nombre e imprimir en pantalla únicamente el resultado final de la suma.

**ESTO ES LO QUE LLEVO**

```
package com.hn.programacion;
public class Arreglotexto_abecedario {
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub String texto= "m"; String [] arregloAbecedario = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x","y", "z"}; System.out.println("Texto de String en la posicion 19= " + arregloAbecedario [19]); 
for (int indice = 0; indice < arregloAbecedario.length; indice ++){ 
String elemento = arregloAbecedario [indice];
```

Comment: saludos y bienvenido, debes leer [ask] y agregar lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento; no es muy bien visto en esta comunidad llegar y pedir algo; todo lo contario si muestras avance recibirás ayuda

Comment: Tengo esto hasta el momento.

Comment: package com.hn.programacion;

public class Arreglotexto_abecedario {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  String texto= "m";
    
                     
  String [] arregloAbecedario = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x","y", "z"};
  
  System.out.println("Texto de String en la posicion 19= " + arregloAbecedario [19]);
  
  for (int indice = 0; indice < arregloAbecedario.length; indice ++){
   String elemento = arregloAbecedario [indice];

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que los caracteres que vas a usar son todos en minuscula, puedes convertir caracteres a su valor ASCII de la siguiente forma

```
int asciiValue = (int) character;
```

La "a" (Minuscula) tiene un valor ASCII de 97. Para obtener su peso puedes hacer

```
int charWeight = asciiValue - 96;
```

Creo que con eso ya puedes resolver el problema.

EDIT: Esto es asumiendo que cambies el array de tipo String (Innecesario) a tipo Char.

Answer (score 0):

Saludo, aquí te dejo una solución. Modifícalo u optimízalo según tus requerimientos.

```
public void algoritmo(){
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     String entrada = scanner.next();
     System.out.println("Entrada: "+entrada);

     scanner.close();

     char letras[] = entrada.toCharArray();
     int total = 0;

     for(char caracter : letras){
        System.out.println("letra: "+caracter+" valor:"+Integer.valueOf(caracter)); 
        total += caracter;
     }

     System.out.println("total: "+total);

}
```